# Spring circular dependencies only on linux build

Tags: java, linux, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a problem with a spring boot app (1.4.1) and I have no clue what is happen:

The app failed to start due to a "circular dependency" error, but this only happens, when I package the app on our CI server (Ubuntu).

We tried following stuff so far:

- Running via IntelliJ and Maven on Windows is working
- Running package on the Windows machine and then execute the war is working on Windows and Linux.
- Running package on the Linux CI machine and then execute the war is not working on windows and not on Linux.
- tried all profiles and there is no difference - so this does not affect anything
- same versions of JDK and Maven on CI and Windows machine

Similar problems only say that running on windows works, but not on linux, which (mostly) happens, because the ordering of "resolve and list resource-files" is system-dependent and therefore the ordering of dependency loading is different.
But this would indicate that the packaged version from the CI-system should run on Windows (or the packages version from windows should not run on linux). But it does not!

Since we have no other ideas: what can we investigate?

Comment: I might had the same issue (never tried building on Windows, only on macos). We have a quite complex spring (framework) application and when we tried to switch from plain tomcat to spring boot we also got the circular dependencies issue, as I said, I never built our spring boot stuff on Windows, our solution at that time was not switching to spring boot :(
I'm not sure how complex it is for you, but you might also try without spring boot and with plain tomcat and spring framework instead. My guess is that there is some strange behavior in spring boot.

Comment: Ok, that's not an option, because the system, which is also quite complex, is built totally on spring boot. Another reason: we like spring boot :)